# C++ / Qt: Changing the starting point of the visible area of a Qt Chart

Tags: c++, linux, qt, charts, frontend

Every Qt chart's visible area start (lower left point of visible area) from axis x:0, y:0. Let's say I want to change the lower left point from (x: 0, y:0) to (x:0, y:300). Obviously you could do a

> chart->scroll(0,300)

But since this has to be changed dynamically multiple times i need a way to give an exact point and set the chart's visible area's starting point to be with its coordinates. Is there a way you could do that in qt because i cant seem to find it.

EDIT:
[image: Like so]

Comment: Could you clarify? I'm not sure what you mean by "starting point to be with its coordinates"

Comment: @TCouch I've added an image representing the question